# R - is there a limit to data that can be passed to an R file via RScript

Tags: r, args, rscript

I'm invoking RScript via this command:

RScript myScript.R var1, var2, var3

This works if the length of variables is small. However, as soon as it exceeds a certain length (say over a 1000 characters) it breaks. Is there a limit to the length of string variables I can pass and/or is there a limit to the total (var1 + var2 + var3) data size I'm able to pass as arguments to the RScript.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the length of the variables in the script?

Comment: it depends on the operating system that you use (max length of a command in shell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum length of the command line arguments is determined by the operating system and shell you are using.

If you are using Linux you can query the max length:

```
~$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
```

PS: The max length could be restricted by the implementation of `RScript` (no idea about this).